# Symfony 2 FOS RestBundle - how to get entity inside controller

Tags: symfony

I there some way to get Entity name from controller which implements ClassResourceInterface?

User Controller:

```
class UserController extends AbstractRestController {
}
```

Common Controller:

```
abstract class AbstractRestController 
    extends FOSRestController 
    implements ClassResourceInterface 
{
    public function cgetAction(Request $request){
        $enityName=????? // Shoud be "User"
    }       
}
```

Comment: What you are asking is pretty strange. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need the entity name?

Comment: Because I'm using commong methods for all entities.
AbstractRestController does not know that enity name is "User"